# _tkinter.TclError: wrong # args: should be ".!entry4 insert index text"

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to list all the data i got from my database using tkinter.
I'm following this post: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/create-table-using-tkinter/

I got this erorr:

```
File "/Users/nobu/WorkSpace/Python/CommandLineApps/guineapig/guineapig/gui_tkinter.py", line 18, in __init__
    self.entry.insert(END, result[i][j])
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/tkinter/__init__.py", line 3056, in insert
    self.tk.call(self._w, 'insert', index, string)
_tkinter.TclError: wrong # args: should be ".!entry4 insert index text"
```

Here's my code:

```
from tkinter import *
import mysql.connector
import utils


class Table:
    def __init__(self,root, result):
        # code for creating table
        total_rows = len(result)
        total_columns = len(result[0])
        for i in range(total_rows):
            for j in range(total_columns):    
                self.e = Entry(root, width=20, fg='white')
                self.e.grid(row=i, column=j)
                self.e.insert(END, result[i][j]) # <- Here I got an error

def get_all():
    connection, cursor = utils.connect_db()
    with connection:
        root = Tk()
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM item ORDER BY item_id DESC")
        result = cursor.fetchall()
        if len(result) == 0:
            label = Label(text="There are no items. Please create one.")
        else:
            table = Table(root, result)
            root.mainloop()
```

I'm very new to tkinter. Please help me solve this issue.

Comment: What have you done to debug this? Have you verified that `result[i][j]` is a string and not `None`?

Comment: Oh, I have `None` value in my list. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you @Bryan Oakley!
My list has `None`, so I did this:

```
if result[i][j] is not None:
    self.entry.insert(END, result[i][j])
else:
    self.entry.insert(END, "None")
```

Comment: I recommend that you accept your answer so that others know the question has been satisfactorily answered.

Comment: `You can accept your own answer in 2 days` shows up when I try to do so.

Comment: Ok! Thanks for trying, just accept it as soon as you can.